# Send emails using auto script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get Gsheets to send to multiple emails. It is gathering information from `A2` & `A3` only. How do I fix this?

```
function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
var subject = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
var message = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Based on your question, I understand that you have fixed `subject` and `message` and you want to iterate over a list of emails.

- You said `A2 & A3` but then in your code for the emails you iterate over column A so it does not make sense to also have the subject and the message in the same column that you have the emails.

### Solution:

Assuming the following sheet:

[image]

here is how you can send emails based on column A with subject and message based on cells `B2` and `B3` respectively:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const subject = sheet1.getRange('B2').getValue(); // B2
  const message = sheet1.getRange('B3').getValue(); // B3
  const n=sheet1.getLastRow();
  const emails = sheet1.getRange('A2:A'+n).getValues().flat();
  emails.forEach(emailAddress=>{                 
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);           
  });     
}
```

If you have a different data structure, let me know and I will modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote that incorrectly. I have the email address in A2, subject in B2 and the message in C2.

Comment: @Alyssa thanks for your feedback. Why do you need an iteration then? how many emails do you want to send?

Comment: Here is a link. Thanks for your help. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XH8l6_ePzCGfIckmbkwxlLqzcYiJ0OugL86pKnxLZfg/edit?usp=sharing